# Precise positioning of content (emulation of TexText behavior)

Tags: positioning

### TL;DR

Suppose we are given

1. the absolute coordinates of a point on a page relative to the upper-left corner of the page, and
2. the LaTeX code for some content, say a displayed unnumbered equation.

**How can one, from within a LaTeX document, position this content so that the upper-left corner of the *tightest box* around it is at the given absolute coordinates on the page?**

The key here is that the box really should be **the tightest,** in the same sense in which [`TexText`](https://textext.github.io/textext/) manages to find the tightest box of the content it generates in [`Inkscape`](https://inkscape.org/):

[image]

Since I cannot be sure that the above isn't an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), below I will also explain what it is I am *really* trying to do.

### TL;DR for what I am *really* trying to do (possibly off-topic here)

**Given an Inkscape-generated SVG file that contains one or several objects created by TexText, how can one convert it to a PDF such that in that PDF, the content created by TexText is searchable and uses fonts rather than outlines, just as if it were generated from a normal LaTeX document?**

The other content in that PDF should be the same as if we generated the PDF from SVG as usual, e.g., using the command-line command `inkscape --export-type="pdf" <name of SVG>`).

(I know about the Inkscape option 'Omit text in PDF and generate a LaTeX file'. Unfortunately, it can't be used to handle TexText.)

### Introduction

Suppose we are given an Inkscape-generated SVG file, which includes one or more objects generated by TexText (via the `pdfLaTeX` engine). For each TexText-generated object, I would like to generate a LaTeX file. This LaTeX file, when compiled (either via `pdfLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`) , should generate a page that has the same size as the Inkscape-generated one, but which contains only the content that is *visually* identical to the TexText-generated object under consideration, including its size (which is easy) and its **exact placement on the page** (which, so far, I can't quite do). Moreover, whereas the Inkscape+TexText-generated PDF isn't searchable and uses outlines rather than fonts, the LaTeX-generated PDF should (as is usual with LaTeX) be searchable and use fonts rather than outlines.

(Eventually, I hope to be able to automate the generation of the LaTeX files via e.g. a `python` script. But I am not asking for the python script; I am only asking about the LaTeX part.)

### Why might one want to do this

My main motivation is the following.  When we convert the Inkscape-generated SVG file into PDF, the TexText-generated part isn't searchable. This is related to the fact that TexText converts pdfLaTeX-rendered content into SVG outlines.

Now, even when the PDF is non-searchable and uses outlines rather than fonts, in principle there are ways to use OCR to turn this nonsearchable PDF into a searchable one (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054750/how-to-make-a-vector-pdf-searchable-using-free-tools-on-linux/71056258#71056258)). However, having played around with [`tessaract`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr) and several other free OCR engines, I have not yet found a way to do this **reliably** *and* **automatically**.

Furthermore, there may well be reasons (independent of the issue of searchability) to prefer, in a PDF document, using fonts rather than outlines. For example, if there is a lot of text, then the PDF file using fonts will be considerably smaller than the one using outlines.

Inkscape actually has a feature that comes close to exactly what I want. Namely, one can write LaTeX code directly into Inkscape as plain text. The code is not rendered within Inkscape. But then we can save a copy of the project as PDF **using the option** 'Omit text in PDF and generate a LaTeX file' (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975786/inkscape-pdf-latex-export/41110512#41110512)). Inkscape then generates a PDF file that has all text omitted, and also an auxiliary LaTeX file. At the end, the PDF will be included in the LaTeX document using `\includegraphics`, and the LaTeX code we originally included as text in Inkscape will be placed into `\put` commands, which will place the result atop the included PDF. This is indeed the situation I want to have: LaTeX content is generated normally by LaTeX, the resulting PDF will be searchable and use fonts, and the LaTeX-generated content will be placed at the same position where we had originally placed it in Inkscape.

**But I really want to be able to use TexText, so I can see immediately what the final product will look like.**

### A way to get started

Well, it turns out that when one uses TexText, the Inkscape-generated SVG file contains not just the outlines, but also the LaTeX code we entered into TexText, the location of the file containing the LaTeX preamble that was used to render this code, the *x*- and *y*-coordinates of the TexText-rendered object, and the magnification. And of course SVG also contains the canvass size.

The idea is that one can write e.g. a python code that will extract all this information and *automatically*, for each TexText-generated object in the SVG file, generate a LaTeX document. This document, when compiled, should generate a PDF that has the same size as the PDF generated by Inkscape, but that contains only the content from that TexText object, now searchable and using actual fonts. Moreover, the content should be of the same size and at the same position as its counterpart in the Inkscape-generated PDF.

Another way to put it, I would like to be able to emulate in LaTeX the behavior of TexText.

### Some relevant details on how TexText behaves in Inkscape

When you enter some content in TexText and save it, Inkscape displays it in a box that is **perfectly tight** around the rendered content, regardless of whether it is an equation or text. For example, if we enter the following into TexText (assuming we load `amsmath` in the TexText's LaTeX peamble),

```
\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{1+x^{2}}&=\sin x \\
  \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}&=e^{-1-\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}
```

we get the following output in Inkscape:

[image]

Note that the (movable and resizable) box that delineates the TexText-generated content is *perfectly tight*; for example, the upper left corner lines up with the uppermost and the leftmost extent of the square root sign.

(For all I know, TexText accomplishes this 'tight boxing' at the level of SVG, i.e. only after the LaTeX code has been rendered and converted to SVG. But I don't actually know.)

If we now manually set the *x*- and *y*-coordinates of this object to 0 and 0,

[image]
the uppermost extent of the square root perfectly aligns with the top of the top edge of the canvass, and its leftmost extent with the left edge of the canvass:
[image]
More generally, the numbers we enter as the *x*- and *y*-coordinates of a TexText-generated object will be the coordinates of the upper-left corner of a *perfectly tight*  bounding box of the TexText-generated content.

### What I want to be able to do in LaTeX

**I would like to be able to emulate the behavior of Inkscape+TexText in LaTeX,** including having the positioning be relative to the upper left corner of the page. We can assume the following as input information

1. the size of the page
2. the LaTeX code (that was placed into TexText)
3. the *(x, y)* coordinates of the upper-left corner of the content, relative to the upper-left corner of the page
4. the magnification setting of TexText.

These are all things that can be easily extracted as plain text from the Inkscape-generated SVG file. An example of something that ***cannot*** be easily extracted is the width and height of the TexText-rendered object. These are visible in Inkscape (next to 'W:' and 'H:') once we 'select' (in Inkscape's sense) the object. But these numbers do not appear as such within the SVG file. Rather, Inkscape has to compute them at runtime. Information like this—which doesn't appear explicitly in the SVG file, but which rather has to be generated by Inkscape at runtime—I will assume we cannot supply to our LaTeX code. (You might think that `\widthof` and `\heightof` will give us these numbers in LaTeX. However, especially for equations generated e.g. by `align`, these two commands will return the dimensions of a box that is generally **not** perfectly tight.)

### My attempt to do this

It is easy enough to create a page of exact same size as the Inkscape canvass. For absolute positioning of general objects (text or equations, including those generated by e.g. `align`, as in the example above), so far I have been trying to use `\put` inside a `picture` environment, just like Inkscape does it when we save to PDF using the option 'Omit text in PDF and generate a LaTeX file'  (see above). However, the next steps I haven't been able to quite figure out.

Take the two equations generated by `align`, from the example above. The closest I got is this. I place the LaTeX code from TexText into a `minipage` of zero width. (The zero width already won't work if instead of `align` we use e.g. `\[…\]`… but let's continue with the present example.) Then I place that minipage into a modified version of `\put` inside a `picture` environment. Here is an MWE. It will attempt to place the equations in the upper-left corner of the page, just like we did with TexText in Inkscape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{calc}

% The following two numbers can be automatically read from SVG. 
% By Inkscape's default, they are in mm.
\newcommand{\DocWidth}{162.81847}  
\newcommand{\DocHeight}{109.87428}

\usepackage[papersize={\DocWidth mm,\DocHeight mm},margin=0mm]{geometry}

% for a cheap way to use 'calc' to do simple arithmetic with *numbers*
% rather than lengths, turn numbers into lengths---in pt---and then 
% strip the lengths. 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mymath}{\strip@pt\dimexpr}
\makeatother
% e.g. '\mymath (12pt + 2pt)/7*11/10' returns '2.2'

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


% Since we'll need to know the height of our content, let's save the content 
% into a macro
\newcommand\mnpgA{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0pt}
% here enter the exact same LaTeX code as was entered into
% TexText, which can be automatically read from SVG
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1+x^{2}}&=\sin x \\
\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}&=e^{-1-\frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}

% measure the height
\newlength{\HeightOfMinipage}
\setlength{\HeightOfMinipage}{\heightof{\mnpgA}}

% I want the positioning to be relative to the upper left corner, 
% whereas by default it is relative to the lower left corner. 
% So I define a new command that does the necessary calculations.
% This is where we use the height we just measured.


\newcommand{\mmPerPt}{0.35145980351459803515} % = (25.4 mm/inch)/(72.27 pt/inch)
%
\newcommand{\putt}[3]{\put(#1,\mymath \DocHeight pt-\mmPerPt\HeightOfMinipage-#2 pt){#3}}
% Remember, \put takes its position arguments as pure numbers,
% expecting them to be in millimeters. (Actually, it will 
% take them to be multiples of \unitlength, and the latter will
% be set to 1mm in this document.) 
% But our cheap calculator \mymath does computations with lengths
% in pt, before stripping the pt.


\begin{document}
%
% let's make the vertical space around displayed equations
% as small as we can
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
%
\begin{picture}(\DocWidth,\DocHeight)
\putt{0}{0}{\mnpgA}
\end{picture}
%
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the output isn't quite right. Let's zoom at the upper left corner:
[image]
Notice that there is a gap between the top of the page and the top of the square root, and also a gap between the left edge of the page and the leftmost point of the square root. But in the Inkscape+TexText-generated PDF we saw above, there were no such gaps.

### A less desirable way to proceed: via an intermediary EPS file

The stumbling block in the approach described above is, in effect, that the invisible box around the content of interest isn't perfectly tight. We could try to make it tight in the following way:

We could generate a PDF of the content of interest as usual. In this initial PDF, the invisible box around content is not necessarily perfectly tight. Next, we convert this PDF file to EPS using `pdftops -eps`. This EPS has a bounding box that is as big as the PDF from which it was produced. Then we apply `ps2eps` to the EPS file, which produces another EPS file. This second EPS file will have a tight bounding box around the content; this is what we were after. Finally, we convert this second EPS file back to PDF using `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop`, so that the visible page in the resulting PDF  has the exact same size as the visible page in the EPS. This final PDF is tightly bounding the content. It can then be included and precisely positioned on the page using `\put` and `\includegraphics`.

One downside of this approach is that it involves extra steps outside of LaTeX. More seriously, though, the results still aren't always perfect; often enough, the bounding boxes are either just a bit too tight or too loose. Look, for instance, at the following example that was done using this procedure (the LaTeX content in this case was just the lower of the two equations we've been considering so far). We zoom in at the upper left corner:
[image]
Notice that the top of the upper '1' has been clipped. At the same time, there is a small gap between the left edge of the page and the left edge of the fraction line.

One could, alternatively, put the EPS file directly into `\includegraphics` and let pdfLaTeX carry the conversion to PDF. The result is below. Again, good, but not perfect; there are small gaps both at the top and to the left.
[image]

### Summary

How can I emulate, in LaTeX, the Inkscape+TexText behavior I decribed ? The solution should work for a wide variety of LaTeX content: `align`, `\[…\]`, `$…$`, mixed plain text and equations… anything that can be entered (and work properly) in TexText. I want to be able to just enter the same LaTeX code as that I entered into TexText, and the *x*- and *y*- coordinates and magnification, and have the result be in the exact same position where it is in the Inkscape+TexText-generated PDF. Also, the solution should be something that can be (reasonably) easy to automate in python. (Meaning, given an SVG, a python script will generate as many LaTeX documents as there are TexText-generated objects in the SVG, so that each LaTeX document gives a PDF with properties as described above.) The LaTeX-generated PDF should, unlike the Inkscape+TexText-generated one, be searchable and use fonts rather than outlines.

I am not asking for the python code here, only for how to make the LaTeX part of the story work. If the extra facilities of `LuaLaTeX` help, they can be used too.

I may be overlooking a completely different approach, but as far as the approach I am currently trying, **the stumbling block is that I don't know how to place arbitrary LaTeX content into a perfectly tight invisible box,** something that TexText seems to know how to do (perhaps at the level of SVG, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Joking: Is there a TL;DR version?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That's a good point, actually. I've now added a TL;DR at the beginning of the question.